# Math.Truncate (decimal) only assignment, call, increment, decrement, etc error

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert a .vb file to C#, and while I've mostly been successful I have come across an error that I'm not sure how to fix.  When trying to use the following line of code:

```
    w = (Math.Truncate((decimal p % sourceImage.bmpData.Stride) / 4));
```

I get an error message stating that "only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

I have searched for a solution to this problem, but have so far been unsuccessful.  Can anyone help me understand what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you post the original VB.NET code line please?

Comment: w = ((p Mod sourceImage.bmpData.Stride) \ 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unclear what you expect from defining variable `decimal p` inside expression in your code, so following will compile, but may not work for you:

```
w = (Math.Truncate((p % sourceImage.bmpData.Stride) / 4));
```

Possibly you are looking for casting to non-integer type with `(float)`/`(decimal)` like following:

```
w = (Math.Truncate(((float)p % sourceImage.bmpData.Stride) / 4));
```

For details on the error check MSDN - [CS0201](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k626bk8b.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that for me, that won't compile.  When I try and build/run without some indicator, I get an error message saying: "Error 1 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Truncate(decimal)' and 'System.Math.Truncate(double)' "

Comment: Thanks Alexei!  It was complicated because I was doing double/decimal math (either would have been okay for my purposes here) but that casting was causing trouble.  I ended up doing a slight variation on your answer, separating some of the math as follows:  
double temp = (double)(Math.Truncate(((double)p % sourceImage.bmpData.Stride) / 4));

                    w = (int)temp;